# Using nm-tool: what does the device "capabilities" mean?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, networkmanager

I'm learning about the use of the Network Manager tools in Linux.

So I've tried using `nm-tool` in my terminal. I'm connected to the internet using a wireless 150 Mbps adapter.

When I run the command, I get something like:

```
Device: wlan0  [miConexion] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k_xxx
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        F3:EF:30:99:71:A0

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           72 Mb/s
```

The line that intrigues me is **"Capabilities: Speed: 72 Mb/s"**.

**What does it mean?** Is 72 the speed that the device is actually receiving at this moment in time, or is the total capacity that the device has.

As the wireless adapter is very old, I want to know if it capacity is somewhat diminished permanently or it just mean that it cannot receive more because of external reasons.

Comment: I hope you made up that MAC address, because that's a multicast address, not a unicast address. It should never be used as a card's hardware address.

Comment: Yeah, that's a made up address ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is the current max speed of which you are capable of utilizing. This number will change from time to time due to signal strength, card capabilities and your wireless access point's capabilities.